# Print arrays from one method in another

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I created a string array and a 2d double array and populated both with values inside the initializeData() method. Now I'm trying to display the arrays inside the displayData() method.

I managed to display the data inside initializeData() using nested for loops.

```
for(int i = 0; i<students.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(students[i] + "  ");
        for(int j = 0; j<grades.length; j++) {
            System.out.print(grades[i][j] + "   ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
```

How can I use this same loop above in displayData() and display the arrays in the method initializeData() ?

```
public class Assignment2 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    initializeData();
    displayData();
}

/**
 * Method that initializes 5 students and grades for 5 courses and populates data.
 */
public static void initializeData() {
    //create arry with student names
    String[] students = {"James", "Luke", "Alex", "Jenny"};

    //create 2d array and populate it
    double grades[][] = {{98, 72, 85, 77, 90},{25,49,26,77,60},{13,8,46,52,28},{77,81,85,69,88}};
}

/**
 * Method that takes the data from initializeData() and displays it to the screen.
 */
public static void displayData() {

}
```

Comment: Have you learned about class variables, `return` statements,  or parameters?

Comment: As @cricket_007 mentioned, method parameters are what you’d need

Comment: Also, might want to learn about classes, because "parallel arrays" usually causes problems. One `Student`  object holds a name and a list of grades. And you then make one `Student[]` to loop over

Comment: I've used return statements and have accessed methods all from inside the main method. This is the first time trying to do this without using the main method. When I try initializeData(students) i get get errors. Also @cricket_007 I have the students array separate only because I cannot mix strings and doubles in one array

Comment: You can mix strings and doubles in an `Object[]`... or, as stated, once you learn classes, a `Student[]` is the better way to do this. But I assume you meant `displayData(students)`, which, yes, is an error... That method accepts no parameters

Comment: So is there anyway to modify the for loop, put it inside displayData() and have it work just like when I put the for loop inside initializeData() ?

Comment: I suggest you learn about **scope** of variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your arrays are locally scoped to the initialize method, and you have two objects, so you cannot return them both back to the main method, so your only option (other than calling the display method from the initialize one)  is to use class variables to move the variable scope to the whole class

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Assignment2 {

    static String[] students;
    static double[][]  grades;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        initializeData();
        displayData();
    }

    /**
     * Method that initializes 5 students and grades for 5 courses and populates data.
     */
    public static void initializeData() {
        //create arry with student names
        students = new String[] {"James", "Luke", "Alex", "Jenny"};

        //create 2d array and populate it
        grades = new double[][] {{98, 72, 85, 77, 90},{25,49,26,77,60},{13,8,46,52,28},{77,81,85,69,88}};
    }

    /**
     * Method that takes the data from initializeData() and displays it to the screen.
     */
    public static void displayData() {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(students));
    }
}
```

---

The other option includes methods like this, but it is up to you to learn about custom classes

```
Student[] initializeData() {} 
void displayData(Student[] students) {} 

static void main (String[] args) {
    Student[] students = initializeData();
    displayData(students);
}
```

Comment: `students = {"James", "Luke", "Alex", "Jenny"};` and `grades = {{98, 72, 85, 77, 90},{25,49,26,77,60},{13,8,46,52,28},{77,81,85,69,88}};` are giving me illegal start errors. `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(students));`  error says cannot find "Arrays"

Comment: 1) You didn't define static variables. 2) That's just an example. Delete it and put your own code

Comment: I did define static variables, when I try to give students a value inside initializeData() it says it's an illegal start of expression

Comment: Thank you very much, glad to know how to use class variables !